# Get NumericProperty of ReferenceListProperty kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have some code:

```
A = NumericProperty(1)
B = NumericProperty(2)

C = ReferenceListProperty(A, B)
```

How I can get NumericProperty of ReferenceListProperty back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C[0]` returns A and `C[1]` returns B

Here is a small Example App with your values, which prints A and B from C (.py)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    Button:
        text: 'print A via ReferenceListProperty'
        on_press: print(root.C[0])
    Button:
        text: 'print B via ReferenceListProperty'
        on_press: print(root.C[1])
""")
class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    A = NumericProperty(1)
    B = NumericProperty(2)
    C = ReferenceListProperty(A, B)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```